# what is <soap12:body use="literal"/>

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am trying to understand this [WSDL file](https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx?wsdl), which defines the service for Quickbooks Web Connector (QBWS).

It is an exe program running on your local laptop and talk to other web service in the clould, e.g.: syncing an invoice from web service.

I've read some articles about, WSDL and SOAP, but when it comes to this block, I don't understand:

```
<wsdl:input><soap12:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input>
```

if you search "literal" in the above WSDL file, there are  many. **What is "use=literal"?**

Comment: love it: In simplest definition, literal it means that the data is serialized according to a schema